# difference between critical point and turning point?

Tags: calculus

Whats the difference between the critical point of a function and the turning point?

aren't they both just max/min points?

Comment: @EricStucky elaborate? for example f'(x) = x(x-1)^2 <-- doesn't this function have one minimum (0), thus 1 critical which in turn is a turning point?

Comment: It does have a minimum, but that minimum is $1$, not $0$.

Answer (score 2):

A function can have critical points that are not turning points.  For example, $0$ is a critical point of the function $f(x) = x^3$ but not a turning point of the function.

For continuously differentiable functions, the critical points can be divided into three types: local maxima, local minima, and inflection points.  The first two types constitute the turning points.  Loosely speaking, inflection points are points that look like the function $f(x) = x^3$ (or $f(x) = -x^3$) looks at $x=0$; the graph of the function flattens out near the point but then continues on in the same direction rather than turning around.

Comment: why isn't that a turning point?

Comment: @Jessica To answer that it would help to know what your definition of a turning point is.  But loosely speaking it is because the graph of the function does not "turn around" at that point.  The function $f(x) = x^3$ never goes from increasing to decreasing or vice versa; it is increasing everywhere (although very slowly near $x=0$ and the tangent line at zero itself is horizontal.)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

Some critical points aren't turning points. For example $x=0$ is a critical point of $f(x)=x^3$.

In some less well-behaved cases, you can even have "turning" points that aren't critical points! Actually, this depends on the definitions you're using; the bad points all exhibit the same behavior as $f(x)=\frac1{x^2}$. Maybe you would want to say that the derivative doesn't exist at $x=0$, in which case it's a turning point also. Or maybe you want to say that that is not a turning point of the function, since it's not defined there.